# How to access and use 1D matrix with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a 1D array of size 12, that inside of each element has a 2D matrix. 
I want to pass as the input of a function the 1D array and inside of the function, in a cycle, I want to go through the array and access the values of the 2D matrix inside of the array.
I am using separate headers.

In my main function, i define the array like:

```
cv::Mat kernels[12];
for(int n =0; n<12; n++){
    cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat::zeros(15, 15, CV_32S);
    kernels[x]=filtro.kernel(n,mat);
    x++;
    }
```

This for cycle adds values to the matrices.

Then I want to insert as input the 1D array in my correlate function, and I do so like this:

```
image_01_c=filtro.correlate(image_01_pad,kernels);
```

In my correlate function I define it like:

```
cv::Mat filter::correlate(cv::Mat& image_in, cv::Mat& kernels)
```

And then, when I want to use the 2D matrices, gives me this error:

```
correlate.cpp: In member function ‘cv::Mat filter::correlate(cv::Mat&,cv::Mat)’: correlate.cpp:41:23: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘cv::Mat’ and ‘int’  kernel_2d=kernels[i];
```

when I use it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    cv::Mat kernel_forca= cv::Mat::zeros(nlines,ncols,CV_32S);
    kernel_2d=kernels[i];
    cout<<"i:     "<< i << flush;
```

Comment: Hmm, I can't spot an operator overload for `operator[](int)` from the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) did you mean to use the `cv::Mat::at()` function?

Comment: I tried to use kernels.at<float>(i), but I think it's only for 2D matrices. So, I used what I showed. I think the problem is the function input.

Comment: you can create a 1D mat with for example: cv::Mat::zeros(1,N,CV_32FC1) and access it with mat.at<float>(0, x) where x < N. OpenCV is optimized for 2D mats (images) and so are many openCV functions.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't seem to be working either. I think the only way is to use 3D matrices, but it always gives me segmentation failure.

I can't use <float> or <int>